# PluginRegistrantCallback is not set in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I got this error when I run my app and the background notifications when app is closed doesnt work:

`firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3`

```
final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    registerNotification();
  }



  void registerNotification() {
    firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();

    firebaseMessaging.configure(onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onMessage: $message');
      return ;
    }, onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onResume: $message');
      return Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => NotificationsScreen()));
    }, onBackgroundMessage: _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler,
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onLaunch: $message');
      return;
    });

    firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      print('token: $token');
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Consultant')
          .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
          .update({'deviceToken': token});
    }).catchError((err) {
      //Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: err.message.toString());
    });
  }
```

out from the class:

```
Future<dynamic> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
    Map<String, dynamic> message,
    ) async {
  // Initialize the Firebase app
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('onBackgroundMessage received: $message');
}
```

I got : `ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, PluginRegistrantCallback is not set., null, java.lang.RuntimeException: PluginRegistrantCallback is not set.`

The problem I figured out is when app is closed I can't get the notifications.
Searching on the internet I see that: `PluginRegistrantCallback is not set`
is an error which involve Application.kt class, but I tried in any manner to put this file unsuccesfully.
Any one has any suggestion?

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error comes from your application file. Make sure register properly.

Application.java

```
package <your package name>;

import com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin;
public final class CustomPluginRegistrant {
    public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        if (alreadyRegisteredWith(registry)) {
            return;
        }
        FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin"));
    }

    private static boolean alreadyRegisteredWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        final String key = CustomPluginRegistrant.class.getCanonicalName();
        if (registry.hasPlugin(key)) {
            return true;
        }
        registry.registrarFor(key);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Add a file in same route called CustomPluginRegistant.java

```
package <your package name>;

import com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin;
public final class CustomPluginRegistrant {
    public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        if (alreadyRegisteredWith(registry)) {
            return;
        }
        FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin"));
    }

    private static boolean alreadyRegisteredWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        final String key = CustomPluginRegistrant.class.getCanonicalName();
        if (registry.hasPlugin(key)) {
            return true;
        }
        registry.registrarFor(key);
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you are not using local notification plugin then can delete that part from code.

Comment: Wherewe need to place these files?

Comment: I assume that we need to place the Application.java into java folder along with CustomPluginRegistant.java

Comment: The path is -> android/app/src/main/java/<your-package-name>/

Comment: Why is the code in Application.java similar to the one in CustomPluginRegistrant?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to go with the `Application.java` workaround using `firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3`, with  and I ended up running into a lot of issues. Fortunately, I've come across an update about how to setup firebase for flutter. As indicated by [the official doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/#3-android-integration) that when you using **Flutter Android Embedding V2 (Flutter Version >= 1.12)**, there are no additional steps required for android. So, we start by adding the following dependencies to pubsec.yaml:

```
firebase_core: ^0.7.0
firebase_messaging: ^8.0.0-dev.15
```

I've included a more detailed answer with code samples in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67187861/6651763).

You run `flutter pub get`. and then follow ***every step*** mentioned in [the doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/#3-android-integration) and you're ready to go.