# Firebase Flutter upgrade problem for firebase messaging

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have upgraded firebase from `^7.0.0` to `^8.0.0-dev.15` and now I am getting erros, that I am not sure how to fix.

Here is my legacy working code:

```
void initFirebase() {
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(
            sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {});
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
      assert(token != null);
      setState(() {
        _notificationToken = token;
      });
    });
  }
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
lib/files/signin.dart:52:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'onLaunch'.
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      ^^^^^^^^
lib/files/signin.dart:62:24: Error: The getter 'onIosSettingsRegistered' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseMessaging'.
 - 'FirebaseMessaging' is from 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-8.0.0-dev.15/lib/firebase_messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'onIosSettingsRegistered'.
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now, I started fixing the code as per the official documentation but cannot get it entirely right, will appreciate your help:

```
  void initFirebase() {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
      (RemoteMessage message) {
        print("onMessage: $message");
      });
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(
      (RemoteMessage message) {
        print("onMessageOpenedApp: $message");
      });
    
    NotificationSettings settings = messaging.requestPermission (
        sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: true,
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {});
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
      assert(token != null);
      setState(() {
        _notificationToken = token;
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using firebase_messaging: `^8.0.0-dev.15`, you should also add with it `firebase_core:^0.7.0`. And there's no "OnResume", "onLaunch", "onMessage", there are other alternatives. Here's how to use it in this case as refered to in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67187861/6651763). For more, you can check [official doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview)

Comment: Nothing is working

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I answered earlier with another question. Besides, I use another major version of flutter and firebase.

So I deleted my answer and opened a new post here: [Flutter 2.0 with Firebase Cloud Messaging: onMessage not called on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66701257/flutter-2-0-with-firebase-cloud-messaging-onmessage-not-called-on-android)

--
EDIT

Does this bug relate to your problem? https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4054

Regards,

Uwe

Comment: Uwinator, thanks for the answer. No this post is not related to my issue. My issue is described here: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/260. A possible solution is described in another post here: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/discussions/4023. The problem is that the upgrade guides are not very clear and I cannot properly update my code. I was hoping for someone with more experience in flutterfire to be able to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This legacy upgrade had some breaking changes. I recreated your problem. The concepts of onresume, onlaunch etc has been reclassified into foreground and background messages.

To handle background messages, at a top level class like you main.dart file, instantiate firebase messaging.

```
Future<void>main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());

}
```

Create a method (_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler) in this case. (If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore, don't forget to call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.).

Background

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
  print(message.data);
}
```

Foreground notifications are slightly different. By default they are not popped on the screen. You can tap into foreground notifications using the method below

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print("Handling a foreground message ${message.notification.body}");
RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;

  if (notification != null && android != null) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        notification.title,
        notification.body,
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            channel.id,
            channel.name,
            channel.description,
            icon: android?.smallIcon,
            // other properties...
          ),
        ));
  }
});
```

You could tap into the message using JSON formatting.

onLaunch: and onResume:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print("app launched or resumed!!");
});
```

The two codes above will display notifications respectively. The background handler also covers for the scenario of a terminated app.

The FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp returns a [Stream] that is called when a user presses a notification displayed via FCM.

PS: In the use of Non-Google servers like PostMan, another breaking change is the requirement of an Oauth-2 Bearer token (short lived, and can be gotten from https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground with a service account.

Answer (score 0):

For your question about-->Error: No named parameter with the name 'onLaunch'.
onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
^^^^^^^^.
What you need to do is replace your code at the _firebaseMessaging.configure(); part to this code:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
   (RemoteMessage message) async {
      print('onMessage: $message');
      _setMessage(message.data);
   },
);
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
      (RemoteMessage message) async {
    print('onLaunch: $message');
    _setMessage(message.data);
  },
);
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
      (RemoteMessage message) async {
    print('onResume: $message');
    _setMessage(message.data);
  },
);
```